# Issue with widths of bars in seaborn barplot

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, width

I am plotting a seaborn barplot in Python, however, the widths of the bars are different when I plot the entire dataset. When I only plot the head of the dataset, I do not have a problem. How can this be solved? Would appreciate any advice!

**Code for plotting the entire dataset, only the head, and outputting the head of the dataframe:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# create dataframes that will be used
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(310), freq='D')
np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data_a = np.random.randint(-20, high=30, size=len(days))
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'date': days, 'a': data_a})
dataframe = dataframe.set_index('date')

dataframe_date = dataframe.copy()
dataframe_date = dataframe_date.reset_index()
dataframe_date['date'] = dataframe_date['date'].dt.date

dataframe_date_head = dataframe_date.head(20)

# plot whole dataframe
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

b_plot = sns.barplot(data = dataframe_date, x=dataframe_date['date'], y=dataframe_date['a'], ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
ax.margins(x=0)
plt.xticks(rotation=70)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(dataframe_date)))
ax.set_xticklabels(dataframe_date.date.apply(lambda x: str(x.day) + '-' + str(x.month) + '-' + str(x.year)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())

plt.show()

# plot only head(20) of the dataframe
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.axes()

b_plot = sns.barplot(data = dataframe_date_head, x=dataframe_date_head['date'], y=dataframe_date_head['a'], ax=ax1)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
ax1.margins(x=0)
plt.xticks(rotation=70)

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(dataframe_date_head)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(dataframe_date_head.date.apply(lambda x: str(x.day) + '-' + str(x.month) + '-' + str(x.year)))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())

plt.show()

# print head of the dataframe
dataframe_date_head
```

[image: entire dataset plot]

[image: head of dataset plot]

```
    date        a
0   2022-03-16  8
1   2022-03-17  17
2   2022-03-18  -3
3   2022-03-19  -8
4   2022-03-20  14
5   2022-03-21  4
6   2022-03-22  2
7   2022-03-23  0
8   2022-03-24  -9
9   2022-03-25  -6
10  2022-03-26  -12
11  2022-03-27  18
12  2022-03-28  -8
13  2022-03-29  26
14  2022-03-30  2
15  2022-03-31  -12
16  2022-04-01  21
17  2022-04-02  22
18  2022-04-03  -8
19  2022-04-04  10
```

**Edit:** I think it is something to do with my environment (I am using Jupyter Notebook on Microsoft edge)

Here is the output using the following code suggested for the bar_plot:

```
b_plot = sns.barplot(data = dataframe_date, x=dataframe_date['date'], y=dataframe_date['a'], ax=ax, color = 'blue', ec='blue', lw=0.5)
```

[image: plot using answer suggestion]

Comment: please provide the sample data as **text**, not image

Comment: I have edited so you also have the data as text. It is also in the code I have provided

Comment: @JohanC yes, unfortunately it produces the same graph

Comment: OK. The default edge color is 'none', so changing the line width won't be visible.  Maybe `sns.barplot(..., ec='white', lw=0.5)`?   Or `sns.barplot(..., color='skyblue', ec='skyblue', lw=0.5)`?

Comment: @JohanC thanks for the suggestion - I would have thought it would work... but strangely the bars are still slightly different widths. I have edited my question to show what I mean

Comment: When bar widths are close to one pixel, it is unavoidable that small diferences will be visible.  You can either try to draw less bars, increase the figure size, or (when saving the plot to a file) increasing the dpi. See e.g. what happens with the letter `m` in this [Wikipedia article about font rasterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_rasterization)

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for the increasing dpi suggestion, it worked for me. Could you please post the answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion in the comments, the answer was increasing the dpi when saving the plot